# How to handle multiple events in the single component in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm developing an UI layer for an application using angular 4, where I have a page layout as shown in below. I have to display the data in the respective table based on the search.

Right now i have the code to display the data in one html(records-list.component.html) that is a part of one component(records-list.component.ts). To display the results based on search, i'm using **onSelect($event)** event of the search boxes. In this case i will have **two onSelect($event)** events, 1 for search1 and 1 for search2.

My question is, what is the best way to handle the events in the components class?
1. Handle both the search box scenario's in single onSelect(event) method?
2. Do i have to split the code into 2 components(also 2 templates)? So that each component will take care of displaying each table data and events?
3. Create a method called **search($event, 's1')** in component and use some parameters to differentiate 2 searches and update the table based on the parameter?

This question may be silly or too simple, but i'm not able decide which way to choose. Please suggest me your ideas. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you need to provide more insight into what you're trying to achieve with this. You might need to split them all - your search boxes and result tables - into another 50 small components based on your task, but the task is totally unclear.

Comment: In the left side table, I will be displaying a list of job names. The user will search for a particular job using search1 option and select a job. Once the job is selected, I will be displaying the information related to the selected job on the right side. The user can use the search2 option to filter the results on the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the difference between events and components a bit. So there is:

1. The concept of smart/dumb components where you emit events. The usual syntax is something along `<my-component (onLeftSelected)="performLeft($event)" (onLeftSelected)="performRight($event)"></my-component>`.

In the 'my-component' you emit the event and define the handlers in the parent component.

**!! BUT
What I would likely do is split up left and right into separate components and declare the related methods in each without the use of emitting events.**

So you'd have a left-component with a `(click)="doSomething(data)"` and a right-component with a `(click)="doVeryImportantStuff(data)"`.

In that case the code would be decoupled and you can reuse either side in other parts in case you need it.

But as @AlexanderLeonov wrote you should first get an understanding of how you want to split that up first.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. Got some understanding of how to proceed. I might have to check more on events.

Comment: @RajashreeGr let me know if I can help you with anything. Decide if you want to do things inside the component or send an event 'up' to the next / parent component.

Comment: I decided to use multiple components with sending an event 'up' to the next/parent event. Thanks for the answer. It helped me to realize my misconception. If I stuck again, I will get back to you.

Comment: @RajashreeGr Great, in that case just define two methods on the parent component and use the child as I wrote on the point 1. Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that approach.